# How can put a Permission on function in NODE-SDK of Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

In ChainCode development, When to have a Multiple organization in the network, In case only a specific Organisation can call a specific function of chain code.

Is it possible in Node-SDK of hyperledger Fabric? if possible then How can implement in development?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `stub.getCreator()` and explore the returned object.

```
let sender = await stub.getCreator();
let senderOrg = sender.mspid;
if(senderOrg=='SpecialOrg'){
    // do your business
} else {
    // whatever
}
```

More information directly in `interfaces.go`: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.4/core/chaincode/shim/interfaces.go

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

(Identity) Attribute Based Access Control (ABAC) can be written into the Smart Contract rather than the NodeSDK client app.

With Fabric 1.4 and the new programming model, the **Client Identity** object is included in the Context object and you can examine the attributes and write your access control logic based on these.

This is the [doc for the client identity object](https://fabric-shim.github.io/release-1.3/fabric-shim.ClientIdentity.html).

And there is a [short section about ABAC](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/users-guide.html#attribute-based-access-control) in the Fabric CA docs.

(ABAC requires that you add attributes to the users when they are registered! )

You could consider using the [beforeTransaction()](https://fabric-shim.github.io/release-1.4/fabric-contract-api.Contract.html#beforeTransaction__anchor) as a place to implement your access control.

There is a "shell" of how this [could be implemented in a typescript example](https://github.com/davidkel/bnaport/blob/master/trade-network/native/fabric-new-ts/contract/src/my-contract.ts#L51).

Comment: @R Thatcher, Thanks for your answer, I will check it.